# Is it possible to access community workspace from mobile browser/phone?

Tags: community

Pretty straightforward question. Error states that "browser version is not supported" but I have the latest version.

Steps to reproduce:

1- Login to a Salesforce org which has an active community with mobile browser (Chrome, Safari etc. with latest version)

2- Request desktop version of site (if you land in mobile version).

3- In Salesforce Classic, enter communities from setup and click workspaces.

Here is the image of error that I am facing.

[image: Error]

Comment: I have tried to replicate using chrome on Android and get the same message. Just looking to see if it is anywhere documented that it is only supported on desktop. Though it is a pretty tough environment to use on mobile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access to Community Workspaces is not currently supported on Mobile.

There is an idea on the [trailblazer community for this](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000LnimQAC)